# file_put_contents: failed to open stream: operation failed when connecting to ftp

Tags: php, ftp

i am trying to upload a file via file_put_contents to two remote ftp servers.

From these two servers "Server A" works fine, but when connecting to "Server B" via file_put_contents, it fails.

Error:

> file_put_contents(ftp://...@serverb.com/test.txt): failed to open stream: operation failed

This is my test:

> file_put_contents('ftp://user:password@serverb.com/test.txt','This is the file data');

I checked both servers on filezilla ftp client and they work fine.

Comment: looks like you don't have permission on file.

Comment: but why does it work with the other server then? i just change the connection details and it works..? when i upload manually over filezilla it works too

Comment: because when you are writing to the file problematically you will not be the root user.